# how to get multiple output (k, v) in one mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

in the **function map** ,in generally you get one (k,v) with output.collect(k,v)

but how i get many (k,v) in one fuction map

i tried the **loop for** like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < liste_cle.length; i++) 
        {
            if (cle_R.equals(liste_cle[i].cle)) 
            {
              ListIterator iterator = liste_cle[i].l.listIterator();
              while(iterator.hasNext())
              output.collect(new Text(iterator.next().toString()), new Text(val_R));
            }
        }
```

for exemple if ***liste_cle.length = 4*** theoretical results is :

**01a abcd**

**01b abcd**

**01c abcd**

**01d abcd**

but the real resulta is :

**01a abcd**    only

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not clear enough. Mapper takes (k1,v1) and produces (k2,v2) as output for each inputsplit (for textinpu format it is a line). So mapper function runs on each input split and generates output key value pairs.
Ex: Input to the mapper:

This is an example

mapper takes each line as an input split. Input to the mapper is (0,This is an example) where key is the offset position and the value is complete line. Then based on your map function logic, it generates the output. So you want to count he number of words then your output would be, 
(This,1) (is,1) (an,1) (example,1).

Now see this mapper has generated the output with various key value pairs. Now this is called intermediate output. Shuffling happens on these before sending these to the reducer. Let me know if this makes sense.